Set a value for repeated records
suppose to have the following:

   ID     DATE1      DATE2    Value
   1    10JAN2019  10FEB2019    1
   1    10JAN2019  10FEB2019    1
   2    01MAR2020  15MAY2020    0
   3    11MAR2022  18JUN2021    1
   3    11MAR2022  18JUN2021    1
   3    11MAR2022  18JUN2021    1     


Is there a way to get the following?

   ID     DATE1      DATE2    Value
   1    10JAN2019  10FEB2019    1
   1    10JAN2019  10FEB2019    0
   2    01MAR2020  15MAY2020    0
   3    11MAR2022  18JUN2021    1
   3    11MAR2022  18JUN2021    0
   3    11MAR2022  18JUN2021    0    


In other words, for repeated rows the "Value" must be reported once and set to 0 for the remaining ones.
Thank you in advance

You are describing what the automatic variable first.<variable> does
data want ;
  set have ;
  by id date1 date2 nostsorted ;
  value = first.date2 ;
run ;

